Can the kinetic energy of electrons be quenched by destroying coherence?
For electrons in a crystal lattice, the itinerant electrons behave as waves and can be decribed by the wavefunction. Is coherence of electrons' wave related to the kinetic energy of electrons? What's more, can the kinetic energy of  electrons be quenched by destroying coherence?

At least in the case of Moire superlattice of twisted bilayer, the momentum of electrons is reduced and the kinetc energy is quenched, but coherence of electrons isn't destroyed.
